# How do I get a full token from a private user in MS Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, access-token

I check the token from the received user in jwt.io - https://i.stack.imgur.com/03OUD.png
From account in organizational directory - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXf2e.png

Permissions app in AD - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekdpv.png

User get token by this instructions - https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs

The main problem is that apparently because of the token, when sending a request `/me/drive/root/children`, the private user receives an empty value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of files from OneDrive from a private user in MS Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560271/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-from-onedrive-from-a-private-user-in-ms-graph)

Comment: No, this is my old question :) @Tiny-wa

Comment: So, is there any differences between these two cases sir?

Comment: Anyway, please first of all have a try with modifying `var scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"];` to `var scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"];` in this line: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs/blob/33e7cc1fd22d3b2db2b842e91318f7d99f96972c/src/tabs.js#L50

Comment: If it doesn't work, may I know if the private user has been invited to your AAD tenant as a guest? I notice that the two screenshots have different tenant_region_scope. So the tenants in the 2 cases are not the same one? Can you provide the detailed decoded access token (including aud, appid and so on) so that we can investigate further?

Comment: Thanks, the option with changing `scopes` helped @AllenWu

Comment: Great! I'll move the comment to answer so this post can be treated as archived. If it's helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `var scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"];` to `var scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"];` in [this line](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs/blob/33e7cc1fd22d3b2db2b842e91318f7d99f96972c/src/tabs.js#L50).

Then the access token will include all the granted Microsoft Graph permissions.